# MySQL get read replica lag

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a MySQL server configured as a read-only read replica.

How to I find out the number of seconds of lag between it and the database being copied?

I tried this:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'seconds_behind_master';
```

But that syntax is not supported.  I'd like a one-liner SQL to retrieve this value.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

**How to get the read replica lag for a mysql server configured as a read only replica.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-slave-status.html

```
show slave status
```

This field `Seconds_Behind_Master` is an indication of how “late” the slave is.

I was able to write a little PHP script which grabs just the one value:

```
$db = new pdo(
    "mysql:host=your_database_hostname;dbname=your_database_name",
    'your_username', 'your_password');

$sql = 'show slave status';

$query = $db->query($sql);
$res = $query->fetchall();

foreach($res as $item){
    print ">" . $item["Seconds_Behind_Master"];
}
```

Which prints 0 seconds because everything is up to date:

```
>0
```

**Here is a little bash command which prints the contents of show slave status for you to parse:**

```
mysql --host=your_host -u your_username --password=your_password your_database_name -e "show slave status"
```